# Почему компиляторы не сообщают о неопределенном поведении

Tags: c++, c

Неопределенное поведение, мягко говоря, неоднозначное решение в дизайне языка. Тем не менее с этим злом приходится жить миллионам программистам. В стандарте, ситуации в которых возникает неопределенное поведение, описаны очень тяжелым техно языком. Неудивительно что большое количество программистов, да что там основная масса, просто не читали стандарт, а если и читали то одну половину не поняли, а вторую забыли.

Самое страшное не столько в том, что неопредленное поведение вообще допускается стандартом или что оно достаточно широко распространено. А в том, что в жизни рядовой программист плохо понимает когда оно вообще возникает. Тем более разочаровывает то, что разработчики компиляторов не стремятся помочь своему клиенту рядовому программисту хотя могли бы, христоматийный пример:

```
int i = 0;
i = ++i + i++;
```

Вот этот код мой MSVC съедает молча. Есть еще не мало ситуаций когда компилятор мог бы предупредить программиста.

Comment: Почему это непределённость? Нужно почитать приоритет действий, расставить правильно приоритеты - тогда будет всё определено.

Comment: Компилятор не должен и не может угадывть что вам нужно. Может  вам именно такое поведение и нужно....

Comment: @nick_n_a, потому что в C++ немного [сложнее](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) с порядком вычисления операндов и побочными эффектами.

Comment: Конкретно для этого случая мой компилятор выдает предупреждение...

Comment: @nick_n_a: С и С++ - не Java. Никакие "приоритеты" тут ничего не определяют.

Comment: А о чём тут сообщать? Загуглите и почитайте про **точки следования**. Всё! Все вопросы отпадают. Просто нужно придерживаться этих простых правил.

Comment: Прежде чем говорить, что неопределённое поведение - зло, советую посмотреть [это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hI8ZVUECb3g) выступление

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почему не сообщают? Потому что не обязаны. Тем не менее некоторые компиляторы могут сообщать о *некоторых* ситуациях, которые могут приводить к неопределённому поведению. Так, если собрать код из вопроса с помощью GCC или clang, Вы получите предупреждение. Есть и другие ситуации, которые покрыты компиляторами, но не все.

Для других ситуаций существуют всевозможные статические анализаторы, типа того же  PVS Studio, clang-tidy (встроен в CLion & Resharper++) и прочих.

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю взглянуть на неопределенное поведение немного под другим углом: в большинстве случаев возникновения неопределенного поведения непосредственно в языковых конструкциях, оно является нарушением со стороны программиста некоторых закрепленных в стандарте требований, без наличия которых эти конструкции вообще не могли бы существовать в нынешнем варианте языка. Другими словами, компилятору прямо позволено рассчитывать, что программист не будет делать некоторых вещей, потому что написание компилятора без такого послабления не представляется возможным.

Простой пример:

```
void Inc(int & x)
{
    x += 1;
}
```

Тут кусок `x += 1;` подразумевает целый букет потенциальных неопределенных поведений:

- `x` может быть ссылкой на невалидный объект
- `x` может быть ссылкой на объект другого типа (ака strict aliasing violation)
- `x` может быть ссылкой на валидный объект, но являющийся частью объекта с const квалификатором
- к значению `x` будет производится доступ из других потоков
- при добавлении 1 произойдет целочисленное переполнение

Никаких вариантов действий, кроме как предположить, что ничего плохого тут не произойдет, у компилятора нет.

Почему язык пришел к такой ситуации - это другой вопрос. Надо полагать, что большая часть проблем такого рода происходит еще из С.

Comment: Разумеется вопрос относится к ситуациям когда программист явно ошибается.

Comment: @Cerbo Ну тогда ответ сводится к тому, что компиляторы сообщают по мере возможностей, а если не сообщают - то пишите вендорам компилятора запрос на добавление фичи. Пример из вопроса кстати порождает предупреждения в g++ и clang++.

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть легаси и/или код, заточенный под определенный компилятор (в том числе автоматически сгенерированный). Ведь поведение не определено лишь с точки зрения стандарта, а у компилятора/платформы всегда есть конкретный ответ на любой вопрос.

Comment: Вы не путаете "неопределенное поведение" и "неспецифицированное поведение"?

Comment: @KoVadim, в данном контексте разница не играет роли. Иначе сообщали бы и не ворнингами, а ошибками.

Comment: " а у компилятора/платформы всегда есть конкретный ответ на любой вопрос." - как бы да, но нет. Известно о поведении clang, который проганял разные оптимизации и в зависимости от того, как они срабатывали, генерил совершенно разный код. А порядок применения оптимизаций для программиста совершенного непредсказуемый.

Comment: @KoVadim, вы правы, но легаси.

Comment: @free_ze: Не бывает такого легаси. Ограничения неопределенного поведения с ходом времени лишь ослаблялись, т.е. неопределенный код становился определенным, а не наоборот. Такое в леаси - невычищенный баг, а не "легаси".

Comment: Утверждение о том, что у компилятора/платформы всегда есть ответ - неверно. В большинстве случаев никакого ответа нет, а он получается в финальном коде недетерминированным с точки зрения "здравого смысла" образом, т.е. как карта ляжет. Может и от выбранного имени переменной зависеть.

Comment: @AnT, попробуйте не возводить утверждения в абсолют и найдется то подмножество, о котором идет речь) Здравый смысл и легаси вообще редко соприкасаются.