# C/C++, неопределенное поведение

Tags: c, неопределённое-поведение

Подскажите, действительно ли для языков C/C++ использование данных, которые имеют в памяти неверное выравнивание, приводит к неопределенному поведению?

Например:

```
char s[100];
float *f = (float*) (s + 1);
*f = 3.1415f;// UB!
```

Кто-то говорит, что если процессор поддерживает доступ к невыровненным данным, то все будет хорошо. А если не поддерживает, что программа либо гарантированно свалится с системным исключением, либо передаст управление системному обработчику, который соберет куски невыровненных данных программно, что исключит падение программы, но замедлит скорость обработки данных на 2-3 порядка.

Я почитал Стандарт, полистал обсуждения этой проблемы на англоязычных сайтах разработчиков ОС и драйверов... И я просто в ужасе. Допустим, процессор сможет в невыровненные данные, но UB на уровне компилятора может сгенерировать такой код, который превратится в бомбу замедленного действия. Которая может сработать при самых непредсказуемых условиях, начиная с выбора имен идентификаторов, заканчивая изменением порядка оптимизаций и расширением количества поддерживаемых фич нового Стандарта для выбранного компилятора.

Есть мнение, что к UB приводит не только обращение к невыровненным данным, то так же и простое задание указателю невыровненного адреса:

```
char s[5];
float *f = (float*)(s + 1);// UB!
```

Если это действительно так, то получается, что 99.9% кода на C/C++, работает на честном слове? Все эти стандартные memcpy(), qsort(), шаманство внутри таких популярных библиотек, как glib...

Да что там glib, я сейчас смотрю на свои проекты (средний объем ~1000-10 000 строк на проект) под новым углом. Я мог ручаться за эти проекты, потому что вылизывал их с особой тщательностью от всяких там UB при переполнении знаковых целых и пр.

Но теперь я за них ручаться не могу.

А бороться с результатом UB - это самое сложное, что я встречал в своей жизни. Стоит мне лишь вспомнить, сколько времени было потрачено на фикс бага, который был связан с переполнением целого. Само по себе переполнение проблему не создавало, но компилятор оптимизировал код так, что мне пришлось расковыривать тонны ассемблера, чтобы понять, что вообще происходит в коде, который был максимально прост и прямолинеен.

И подскажите, пожалуйста, страдает ли Java от UB?

Comment: `memcpy` - реализуется, как правило, на чистом ассемблере, потому что вызов цепной `repe movsb` и её обрамление (регистры esi, edi, еcx) невозмножно реализовать на си (`memcpy` реализованая не на ассемблере - будет работать медленнее, как правило так не делают) И поэтому компилятор её не может "сократить". Вообще если у вас идет вызов библиотечной функции, а не внутренний, то компилятор не может предсказать что делает "внешняя" функция, потому что он не видит её код, следовательно компилятор не может её оптимизировать и вызвать ub.

Comment: А задание указателю адреса с некорректным выравниванием?

Comment: @nick_n_a обычно memcpy реализуется как интринсик компилятора, именно для того чтобы компилятор мог ее сократить...

Comment: @Максим, те, кто пишут компиляторы и ОСи обычно знают, что делать с такими странными штуками. Поэтому, читаете документацию на memcpy для своей платформы и все будет ок.

Comment: Да дело же не в memcpy(). Основной вопрос связан с UB при задании указателю невыровненного адреса.

Comment: Игра с указателями она такая. В с++ лучше с ними не играть. А если сильно хочется, то читать документацию. А код, как у Вас в вопросе - это жуткое дело. И как минимум потому, что есть big-endian и little-endian.

Comment: Функции `memcpy`, `qsort` и т.п. работают исключительно с указателями `char *`. Там нет и быть не может никакого доступа к невыравненным данным. Откуда вы это взяли? Если функция `memcpy` захочет себя оптимизировать пословным доступом, то она сама внутри себя позаботится о том, чтобы этот доступ был выравненным.

Comment: @Максим, в java, как и в c#, понятие ub почти исключили. Их отлов на себя берет виртуальная машина. А разработчик просто пишет код. Исключением может быть взаимодействие с какими-то нативными либами напрямую

Comment: @AnT, а если взять memcpy() и скопировать float в массив char-ов со смещением != sizeof(float)? Это будет UB...

Comment: @Максим: Нет, это не будет UB. Копировать через `memcpy` можно что угодно и куда угодно.

Comment: Да что вы прицепились к этому memcpy()... Я ведь спросил не про memcpy(), а про UB при задании указателю неверно выровненного адреса. memcpy() - это лишь частный случай. И вы неправы, memcpy() запросто может стать причиной UB - например, если вы записываете float в любое место памяти по адресу с неверным выравниванием, а затем используете это значение. Например, при реализации менеджера памяти, при заполнении буфера разными типами данных и пр.

Comment: *"получается, что 99.9% кода на C/C++, работает на честном слове"* - вы попали в самую точку! 100% кода на C/C++ работает исключительно на честном слове, так как ответственность за корректность многих фундаментальных вещей возлагаются исключительно на программиста (см [Почему компиляторы не сообщают о неопределенном поведении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827569/Почему-компиляторы-не-сообщают-о-неопределенном-поведении/827714#827714))

Comment: Что касается неопределённого поведения при преобразованиях указателей, то в С и С++ на этот счет действуют разные правила. В С++ само преобразование указателя в приведенном примере никогда не является неопределенным поведением, а разыменование указателя является неопределенным поведением (даже если выравнивание окажется правильным). В С вроде правила более мягкие и указатель на char может алиасить что угодно. Что касается memcpy, то запись float в любое место не будет неопределенным поведением, а вот код, приведший к использование float с неверным выравниванием - очень даже.

Comment: И что же со всем этим делать?